# number of bytes written by putShort()

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I want to write an enum value and store it to disk by saving a field from it with `ByteBuffer.putShort()` and writing that to disk. This enum is basically a field in a file header.

How much space does `ByteBuffer.putShort()` occupy?

Comment: Are you writing it to disk with Java serialization?

Comment: I don't think you can serialize enums, can you?

Comment: You cannot serialize enums. Write a custom mapper and they can be whatever you want.

Comment: So it really depends on how you save it to disk. You can probably do some compression in some cases, but in general it will be (if you're doing a deep save) the sum of the sizes of all the instance variables.

Comment: you can certainly serialize enums.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't stated how you're writing it to disk, the question is unanswerable.

If however you're referring to serialization, the answer is 'no', as the enum is basically serialized as its string name plus a tag and some type information.

**EDIT** According to your comments and edits, you're actually asking whether `putShort()` writes 16 bits. That's answered in the documentation, and it has nothing to do with how big an enum is.

Comment: I want to save it's value to a ByteBuffer and write that to disk

Comment: How you serialize it will determine how much space it will take. If you used a string, then it will be the size of that string in the encoding you choose.

Comment: Please see the edits. If I do putShort on a ByteBuffer and save the result from 'getTestValue()', that should help me save only 2 bytes? [Serialize the enum to 2 bytes]

Comment: If you're calling `ByteBuffer.putShort`, that will only write exactly 2 bytes.

Comment: @user1071840 Writing a short doesn't constitute serialization in any way shape or form, but it is still documented how many bytes putShort() writes. Two. See the Javadoc.